# How to perform two dimensional neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm quite new in neural network. I saw this code with very good explanation :

```
import numpy as np

# sigmoid function
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

# input dataset
X = np.array([  [0,0,1],
                [0,1,1],
                [1,0,1],
                [1,1,1] ])

# output dataset
y = np.array([[0,0,1,1]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

# initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

    # forward propagation
for iter in range(10000):
    for i in range(3):
        l0 = X[i,:]
        l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0))
        l1_error = y[i] - l1
    # multiply how much we missed by the slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
        l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1,True)
    # update weights
        syn0 += np.matrix(l0.T*l1_delta).T



l0 = [0,0,0]
l0 = [1,0,0]
l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0))
print(l1)
```

I can understand the idea which stays behind this. However, I have no idea how the analogous algorithm can be applied into two-dimensional output. i.e.

```
X = np.array([  [1,1,1],
                [1,0,1],
                [0,1,1],
                [0,0,1],
                [0,0,0],
                [1,1,0]])

y = np.array([  [1,1],
                [1,1],
                [1,0],
                [0,0],
                [0,0],
                [1,1]])
```

Could you please give me a hand with adjusting first algorithm to be compatible with two-dimensional output case ?

**EDIT**

I know that I should change `syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1`
to `syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,2)) - 1`. But it's not the only change that should be done. I get error massage : `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)` when trying to run it with this only changed.

Comment: The dimensions of X i.e. input data is still the same but with just couple of more rows. How is this different from what you already have as input, both are 2-dimensional

Comment: Yes you're right. What I meant is that output is 2-dimenional (it has two values in one bracket instead of one)

Comment: I corrected my question ;))